# Laravel package development register blade section in serviceprovider

Tags: php, laravel, package, service-provider

I'm building a package for the Laravel 5.6 framework. I would like to 
register a blade `@section('content');` so the developer can 
use `@yield('content');` and add that into it's own application.

Currently in my Package serviceProvider I register my views like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', 'views');
}
```

However when add a `@section('content');` to a view in that directory. I cannot use it (`@yield('content');`) in my laravel application views.

I don't want to publish my package views to the Laravel application views!

How could I achieve this? I hope my question is
well formulated. If you've any questions please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: If you add `@section('content')` in view A then be able to `@yield('section')` content in view B you need to include view A in B

Comment: @apokryfos that's not working.

Comment: What's not working? What code is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with `yield()` for this you have to extend blade.

Here is an example, In your ServiceProvider

```
 Blade::directive('datetime', function ($expression) {
        return "<?php echo ($expression)->format('m/d/Y H:i'); ?>";
    });
```

Now you can use it in your views.

```
@datetime(Your date)
```

Hope this helps.